# Vanishing of $H^n(X,\mathcal F)$ for $X$ non-proper

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm currently reading through [Kleiman's proof](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1967-018-05/S0002-9939-1967-0213369-9/S0002-9939-1967-0213369-9.pdf) that $H^n(X,\mathcal F)$ vanishes when $\mathcal F$ is a coherent sheaf on an $n$-dimensional non-proper (reduced and irredicible) variety and got stuck in the proof of Lemma 2, p. 943. The points that are unclear to me are the following:

1. Kleiman casually chooses an irreducible hyperplane section $Y''$. I can see why such a thing exists if we work over an infinite field $k$, but this is nowhere mentioned in the text. Why does this still work?
2. I don't see why $Z+mY''$ is very ample for $m\gg 0$, nor why this implies $X-(Z\cup Y'')$ is affine.

I would be grateful if anyone could clarify this for me.

Comment: First, reduced and irreducible are not essential, only that all irreducible components are non-proper. Since $H^n(X,F)=0$ if and only if the same is true after base change to the algebraic closure, you may base change. Notice that all components are still non-proper. For 2), I assume that $Z$ is a Cartier divisor. This is a standard fact and better to read a proof (not difficult, but requires an argument) for very ampleness. Very ample means gives an embedding of $X$ and use the fact that projective space minus a hyperplane is the affine space.